# CartoDB Timestamp Multiple DATA

Tags: carto, time

Is it possible in CartoDB to have multiple data points for the same timestamp so that when I do things like Torque or other viz it shows up with all the data at that time point? In other words the data would look like:

```
time lat lon
xxx la1 lo2
xxx la3 lo4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, absolutely. You can store whatever data you require to be in the database.

What you are asking is one of the main use cases of Torque.